# Seeking advice: delegating collection-management-responsibility to UserControl that doesn't know the kind of data involved

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I have 3 boxes responsible for showing `Name` of 3 kind of data, say:

```
class Shake { ... }
class Molecule { ... }
class Existence { ... }
```

They all appear in an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Shake> Shakes { get; set; }
...
```

to show/add/remove I use some custom `UserControl` with a `DependencyProperty` of type `ObservableCollection<object>`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof (IEnumerable), 
                                typeof (ListWithTitle), 
                                new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

public ObservableCollection<object> ItemsSource {
    get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

The whole idea is that the `UserControl` is responsible for removing items off of the lists - I don't need to add any code in the container `Window` of these `UserControl`s, but the data itself is part of that container `Window`.

The problem is that: when the `UserControl` needs to remove items, it doesn't know what's the type of that item (it has an `ObservableCollection<object>`, not `ObservableCollection<Shake>`), so this code fails:

```
private void RemoveElementButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    for (var i = TheListBox.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        ItemsSource.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Because the `ItemsSource` property (enclosed above) tries to cast `ObservableCollection<Shake>` to `ObservableCollection<object>`... currently I do:

```
 private void RemoveElementButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    for (var i = TheListBox.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     (GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty) as dynamic).RemoveAt(i);
}
```

but I don't like it much (what if I change `ObservableCollection` to `NewDotNet7AwesomeCollection` some day in the future?)

Now let's say I don't have 3 boxes, but 33... what would you suggest (btw, the collection can change from the outside, so `ObservableCollection` is essential here)?

Comment: Create DP of type `IList` instead. Source collection can still be `ObservableCollection` and can still bind with `IList`. That way you don't have to worry about typecasting.

Comment: Why does it have to be `ObservableCollection<object>`? Just make it `Shake`.

Comment: @RohitVats - this is the direction of what I am looking for, but if I do that, will I still be able to respond to the `ObservableCollection` events?

Comment: @lll - but I need a collection of items, I don't want to force the user to inherit `Shake` or make custom types that hold a collection, I want to adhere to the usual conventions

Comment: @Tal - I have added few more details in answer. See if that what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating over my comment:

> Create DP of type IList instead. Source collection can still be
>   ObservableCollection and can still bind with IList. That way you don't
>   have to worry about typecasting.

you have a question that:

> This is the direction of what I am looking for, but if I do that, will
>   I still be able to respond to the ObservableCollection events?

As per my understanding, you meant to ask if you bind this DP with `ObservableCollection<T>`, will you still be notified of `INotifyCollectionChanged` events i.e. GUI updates on add/delete of objects in source list.

Yes, that's true as long as Source collection is implementing INotifyCollectionChanged (or say `ObservableCollection<T>` in your case), GUI will respond to events properly.

This will work for sure becuase `ItemsSource` property of `ItemsControl` itself is of type `IEnumerable` and still it responds to INCC events. So, in your case it will work too.

---

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IList), 
                                typeof(ListWithTitle));

public IList ItemsSource
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

**PS** - I have suggested `IList` over `IEnumerable` because as per your usage of this property - `ItemsSource.RemoveAt(i);`. You need indexing over and Remove methods which are available for IList and not on IEnumerable. Otherwise you manually have to typecast to IList explicitly like this `(ItemsSource as IList).RemoveAt(i);`. So, that's your call what you want to choose IList or IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a simple base class for your data types. You could implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in it so that you wouldn't have to in each data type:

```
class Shake : BaseDataType { ... }
class Molecule : BaseDataType { ... }
class Existence : BaseDataType { ... }
```

Now your `DependencyProperty` could be a collection of this base type:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", 
    typeof(ObservableCollection<BaseDataType>), typeof(ListWithTitle), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

public ObservableCollection<BaseDataType> ItemsSource {
    get { return (ObservableCollection<BaseDataType>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

So now we data bind this to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property using a `RelativeSource Binding`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourLocalPrefix:ListWithTitle}}}" ... />
```

Then you shouldn't have any trouble removing items:

```
ItemsSource.RemoveAt(i);
```

Comment: This solution doesn't follow the normal conventions of `WPF` regarding collections binding - I won't be able to bind to `ObservableCollection<NonBaseDataType>`, where `NonBaseDataType` doesn't inherit `BaseDataType`

Comment: I have no idea which *normal conventions of WPF* that you are referring to... perhaps you could provide me with a link? And of course you can't add an element that does *not* extend a base class into a collection of the type of that base class... that's basic generics and has nothing to do with *normal conventions of WPF*.